# Realmente no se cuál es el error. Pokedex api

Tags: javascript

Estoy practicando con la pokedex api, y quiero crear una carta con el nombre y la imagen del pokemon ditto.
Me envia al catch cuando invoco la funcion getMap, los datos con el fetch los agarra correctamente, Pero cuando llega al data.map va al catch. Estuve bastante tiempo pero sigo sin poder encontrar el error, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

```
"use strict";
const div = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(div);

async function getData() {
  let url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto";
  try {
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const data = await resp.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch {
    console.log("error");
  }
}

async function getMap() {
  try {
    const data = await getData();
    console.log(data);
    data.map((element) => {
      createObj(element.species.name, element.sprites.front_default);
    });
  } catch {
    console.log("error");
  }
}

function createObj(nombre, imagen) {
  const divObj = document.createElement("div");
  const name = document.createElement("h1");
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  divObj.className = "objetos";

  div.appendChild(divObj);
  divObj.appendChild(name);
  divObj.appendChild(img);

  name.textContent = `${nombre}`;
  img.setAttribute("src", `${imagen}`);
}

getMap();
```

Actualización: al llegar al catch me dice que data.map is not a function

Comment: Cambia el `catch` por `catch(err) { console.log(err) }` y agrega a la pregunta cuál es el error que obtienes en la consola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que la API solo regresa un objeto, y para utilizar la función map ocuparía regresar un array. Para crear una sola carta con la información del objeto ocupas hacer lo siguiente:

```
async function getMap() {

      try {
        const data = await getData();
        console.log(data);
        createObj(data.species.name, data.sprites.front_default);
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
```